# Wrong networkx Graph and visulisations are ugly

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I have dataframe which consists of more than 60 values of (2x2) size and a sample of some data are as follows

```
   label           data_pairs
   -1040         [(-1037.13, -1044.77)]
   -1092         [(-1102.64, -1081.64)]
   -1105         [(-1107.36, -1102.64)]
   -137          [(-136.19, -138.75)]
   -1431         [(-1434.08, -1429.31)]
   -612          [(-622.47, -601.98)]
   -672          [(-669.77, -674.95)]
   -752          [(-748.22, -755.9)]
   -791          [(-795.19, -788.02)]
```

As the name suggests in the datasets, I would like to draw `networkx` graph for the `pair's values` and `label` them accordingly. Based on one of StackOverflow user suggestion, I further modified the codes as per his guidance as follows

```
df=pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Python Scripts\Python 
                 Scripts\uuu\data_pairs.xlsx')   # type: datFrame (10,2)
```

The `networkx` codes are as follows

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()
edges = np.stack(df.Pairs.to_numpy()).reshape(-1,2)   # array of str1248 (5,2)
G = nx.from_edgelist(edges)
pos = nx.spring_layout(G, k=0.6)     # dict

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,2),dpi=300)
nx.draw(G, pos=pos, node_size=800, with_labels=True,node_color='y')
```

`edges` values looks something like this

```
[(-1037.13, -1044.77)]  [(-1102.64, -1081.64)]
[(-1107.36, -1102.64)]  [(-1187.16, -1192.42)]
[(-1261.33, -1280.02)]  [(-136.19, -131.06)]
[(-131.06, -138.75)]    [(-136.19, -138.75)]
[(-1434.08, -1429.31)]  [(-304.94, -308.8), (-304.94, -307.85)]
```

This `networkx` graph I got something like this
[image: this]

As you can see the figures looks wrong because of `edges` values where they are using two values to connect the graph. Also, there is no label shown in graph. For example for `data_pairs` values [(-1037.13, -1044.77)] I should get `label` value -1040 in between the line. Something like this `(-1037.13)--------------------> (-1044.77)` and likewise.
-1040

Above one is just for sake of understanding.

Could you please help me how to get such kind of result? thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Getting an error 'all input arrays must have the same shape' once I use this line and try to define edge.  Is edge line code is correct?

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:igraph] tag unless your question concerns the igraph library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your column contains tuples nested in a list. You need to properly structure the values so that `networkX` builds the rgaph as expected. A simple way is stacking the values into an array, and reshaping appropriately.

Also, `nx.spring_layout` has a parameter `k`, to set the spacing between the nodes in the graph:

```
from ast import literal_eval
from itertools import chain

df['data_pairs']= df['data_pairs'].map(literal_eval)
G = nx.from_edgelist(chain.from_iterable(df.data_pairs))

plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
pos = nx.spring_layout(G, k=.6)
nx.draw(G, 
        pos=pos,
        node_size=800, 
        with_labels=True, 
        node_color='y')
```

[image]

Input data -

```
G.edges()
EdgeView([(-1037.13, -1044.77), (-1102.64, -1081.64), (-1102.64, -1107.36), 
          (-136.19, -138.75), (-1434.08, -1429.31), (-622.47, -601.98), 
          (-669.77, -674.95), (-748.22, -755.9), (-795.19, -788.02), 
          (-304.94, -308.8), (-304.94, -307.85)])
```

Comment: It worked thanks a lot. Just last question, how to show the 'key' in-between nodes?

Comment: Finally :) No worries. What do you mean with key? @ravi

Comment: I faced visualisation problem and I posted as a new question. Can you please have a look and try to help me out?